# How to change Boolean true/false into strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, typescript, luhn

I'm currently working on a project involving validating credit cards, and I have this luhn algorithm:

```
export default function luhn(card: string): boolean {
return (
card.split('').reduceRight(function(prev: any, curr: any, idx) {
  prev = parseInt(prev, 10)
  if ((idx + 1) % 2 !== 0) {
    curr = (curr * 2)
      .toString()
      .split('')
      .reduce(function(p, c) {
        return (parseInt(p, 10) + parseInt(c, 10)) as any
      })
  }
  return prev + parseInt(curr, 10)
}, 0) %
  10 ===
0
)
}
```

Notice the boolean in there? i'm using this as a module for my index.ts which looks like this:

```
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import { createInterface } from 'readline'
import { getCompanyName } from './cardType'
import cardValidator from './cardValidator'

const lineReader = createInterface({
input: createReadStream('data/input.txt')
})

lineReader.on('line', (creditCard: string) => {
  var company = `${getCompanyName(creditCard)}: ${creditCard} (${cardValidator(
creditCard
)})`

console.log(company)
})
```

It currently outputs to the console something like this:

```
MasterCard: 5105105105105100 (true)
MasterCard: 5105105105105106 (false)
```

I want the true/false to be valid/invalid I've looked into it a little bit(w3) but don't know how to integrate anything into my algorithm as it requires you to declare a variable for both  true and false. any suggestions/answers would be much appreciated

Comment: something like ``${getCompanyName(creditCard)}: ${creditCard} (${cardValidator(creditCard) ? "valid" : "invalid"})`` will do ya

Comment: thanks alot, if you make this an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to include the strings you want directly in your output string:

```
var company = `${getCompanyName(creditCard)}: ${creditCard} (${cardValidator(creditCard) ? "valid" : "invalid"})`
```